# Where can I find a solar eclipse calendar compatible with Google Calendar?

Tags: solar-eclipse

For planning purposes it would be good to have a calendar of upcoming (at least some years) solar eclipses. [The closest thing I've been able to find](http://www.andrade.org/eclipse/upcoming) has too many other events in it to be useful. A [similar calendar](http://icalshare.com/calendars?query=solar%20eclipses) is no longer reachable.

Comment: The second link in http://icalshare.com/calendars?query=solar+eclipses might be helpful (not the first link, which has WAYYY too much stuff).

Comment: @barrycarter It's a dead link unfortunately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Responding 6 years and 6 months later, but it’s never too late to answer a good question.

Anyways, the best I’ve come across is definitely “NYT Astronomy and Space Calendar”.
Check out the following link:
https://www.nytimes.com/explain/2023/astronomy-space-calendar

Here is the iCal link for your convenience:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/nytimes.com_89ai4ijpb733gt28rg21d2c2ek@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics

This was surprisingly very hard to find.